# Replace date object in array with a string

Tags: javascript, mongoose

What I want to do is to replace a date object in an array with a formatted string.

I use mongoose (mongoDB) and in a scheme we have an array property and inside another property from type date.
For further processing I need to convert in this array the date object to a formatted string.

Mongoose scheme:

```
testSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
   myArray: [{
      myDateObject: {
         type: Date
   ]}
});
```

Array:

```
 myArray: [{
    _id: 5e85ea217a67326dba35e8b4,
    myDateObject: 2020-10-31T23:00:00.000Z,
 }]
```

I did the following:

```
object.myArray[0].myDateObject = moment(object.myArray[0].myDateObject).format('MM/YYYY');
```

But it's not replacing it with the formatted date.

What I want to do is to replace a date object in an array with a formatted string.

I use mongoose (mongoDB) and in a scheme we have an array property and inside another property from type date.
For further processing I need to convert in this array the date object to a formatted string.

Mongoose scheme:

```
testSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
   myArray: [{
      myDateObject: {
         type: Date
   ]}
});
```

Array:

```
 myArray: [{
    _id: 5e85ea217a67326dba35e8b4,
    myDateObject: 2020-10-31T23:00:00.000Z,
 }]
```

I did the following:

```
object.myArray[0].myDateObject = moment(object.myArray[0].myDateObject).format('MM/YYYY');
```

But it's not replacing it with the formatted date.

Side note: I debugged myArray and it's a CoreMongooseArray, not a typical Array

How can I now achieve to replace this date object with a formatted string?

Comment: what error  are you getting with your approach?

Comment: After using moment format, what did `myDateObject` looked like?

Comment: @sv12 I'm not getting any error - it's simply not overriding it

Comment: @palaѕн Same as before - it's not changing

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-bas-fg1c2 .It works?

Comment: Your code is working fine as you can see in your demo. Maybe you can try to make a clone of `myArray` and then try to updated the cloned array instead.

Comment: I see that in the sandbox it's changing the object to a string - but not in my case.

Comment: @micu, Try object.myArray[0].myDateObject = moment(object.myArray[0].myDateObject, "YYYY-MM-DD").format('MM/YYYY');

Comment: I made a clone:
let myClonedArray = myArray;
And I'm using the cloned array to replace the date object, but unfortunately, no change

Comment: @sv12 I tried and still not replacing.

Comment: I added a side node. It's a CoreMongooseArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I posted is working - it's a mongoose problem that it can't cast it to Date.